# Question about Pandas string manipulation for sampling chat data by answer group

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, chatbot

Question about Pandas string manipulation for sampling chat data by answer group.

Hi, I would like to divide my chat dataset into train and test dataset.
I want to know is there any good approaches with Pandas Dataframe.

**Original Dataframe**

```
1   2   3

A  Hi  Hello, there 

A  How are you  Hello, there

A  What's up  Hello,there

B  What is your name, My name is Thomas

B  May I know your name?  My name is Thomas
```

...

->
**train Dataframe**

```
1   2   3

A  Hi  Hello, there

A  How are you  Hello, there

B  What is your name, My name is Thomas
```

...

**test Dataframe**

```
1   2   3

A  What's up  Hello,there

B  May I know your name?  My name is Thomas
```

...

Basically, [Col 3] (Answer) has several Questions [Col 2] mapping.
I would like to extract sample question and answers 10~20% train&test data based on the same answer group.

It's kinda complicated approaches to recognize it only works when the answer has more than 2 questions.

Is there any good approaches for Pandas dataframe to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by answer group? Your first column? As in extracting 20% from group A, other 20% from group B and so on?

Comment: So, the 3rd group is the key of this dataset. As you see from dataset, there are 3 "Hello, there" sentences for each questions (second column). Therefore, I would like to split by 8:2 or 7:3 whatever if there are more than 2 questions (second column) for one answer ("Hello there")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is kinda sketchy but it works. There isn't a straightforward approach (as far as I know) to extract `n` random samples from sub groups of dataframes. What you can do is group the data by answer and concatenate the questions into a list and then pick a number of random elements. To do so, your dataframe should like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Question': [[['Hi Hello']], [['How are you']], [['Whats up']], [['What is your name']], [['May I know your name?']]], 
    'Answer':['there', 'there', 'there', 'My name is Thomas', 'My name is Thomas']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

## df Output ##
                    Question             Answer
0               [[Hi Hello]]              there
1            [[How are you]]              there
2               [[Whats up]]              there
3      [[What is your name]]  My name is Thomas
4  [[May I know your name?]]  My name is Thomas
```

Now group by answer:

```
new_df = df.groupby('Answer').sum().reset_index()

## Output ##
              Answer                                        Question
0  My name is Thomas  [[What is your name], [May I know your name?]]
1              there         [[Hi Hello], [How are you], [Whats up]]
```

Now iterate each row and selet the rows you want for train and test. Note that in this example the extraction is not exactly random. I pick the first `n` for train and the last `length(answer_group) - n` for test.

```
train_file = open('train.csv', 'a')
test_file = open('test.csv', 'a')

for _, instance in new_df.iterrows():

    n_questions = len(instance.Question)
    splits = int(2 * n_questions / 3) # Assuming you want a train/test split of 3:1

    train = instance.Question[:splits]
    for train_example in train:
        train_file.write(train_example[0] + ',' + instance.Answer + '\n')

    test = instance.Question[splits:]
    for test_example in test:
        test_file.write(test_example[0] + ',' + instance.Answer + '\n')

    ## Files output ##

    # train.csv #
    What is your name,My name is Thomas
    Hi Hello,there
    How are you,there

    # test.csv #
    May I know your name?,My name is Thomas
    Whats up,there
```

The full working code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Question': [[['Hi Hello']], [['How are you']], [['Whats up']], [['What is your name']], [['May I know your name?']]], 
    'Answer':['there', 'there', 'there', 'My name is Thomas', 'My name is Thomas']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

new_df = df.groupby('Answer').sum().reset_index()

print(new_df)

train_file = open('train.csv', 'a')
test_file = open('test.csv', 'a')

for _, instance in new_df.iterrows():

    n_questions = len(instance.Question)
    splits = int(2 * n_questions / 3) # Assuming you want a train/test split of 3:1

    train = instance.Question[:splits]
    for train_example in train:
        train_file.write(train_example[0] + ',' + instance.Answer + '\n')

    test = instance.Question[splits:]
    for test_example in test:
        test_file.write(test_example[0] + ',' + instance.Answer + '\n')
```

**Edit**: I just noticed I got wrong the content of questions and answers, but that's due to the bad formatting of the original post. Either way, the logic is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, although dataset is different from origin, so it does not work directly, but I got the hint and figured out for my question.